# count Float number with Integer in StringBuilder java

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I have products activity i want to count (Float) price * (Integer) quantity for each product than i need the total amount for all products... i tried by this code but the result it's weird orderItems is listview for selected products,

NItems is the quantity, itemprice is the price of each item

```
total_amount = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {

                    total_amount.append(Integer.parseInt(orderItems.get(i)
                            .getNItems()) * Float
                            .parseFloat(orderItems.get(i)
                                    .getItemPrice()));
        }
        if (total_amount.length()== 0)
            return false;
        else
            total_amount.deleteCharAt(total_amount.length()-1);

        Log.d("OrderPreview",total_amount.toString());
```

Comment: What is `orderItems`, what types do `getNItems` and `getItemPrice` return?

Comment: Why are you appending the result of each calculation to a string rather than adding it to a floating point number? Is it that you want to see the result of each calculation rather than the total? You may also wish to put a separator (eg. a space) between each calculation, otherwise they will all run together.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't required to put everything on one line. I suggest breaking the statement into multiple parts. I suspect you wanted to use some form of formatted output and generally (for money) you would use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance--) and then format your *total* with something like

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
total_amount = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {
    int count = Integer.parseInt(orderItems.get(i).getNItems());
    float price = Float.parseFloat(orderItems.get(i).getItemPrice());
    total_amount.append(nf.format(count * price)).append(" ");
}
Log.d("OrderPreview", total_amount.toString());
```

If you wanted a *grand total* that should probably be

```
float grandTotal = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {
    int count = Integer.parseInt(orderItems.get(i).getNItems());
    float price = Float.parseFloat(orderItems.get(i).getItemPrice());
    grandTotal += (count * price);
}
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
total_amount = new StringBuilder();
total_amount.append(nf.format(grandTotal));
Log.d("OrderPreview", total_amount.toString());
```

Comment: thank you Sir your code is correct but i need the total amount for the invoice i did it in another activity  and it was correct but i don't know why it's not work correct(it's give results but it's wrong but in  here this code it is correct:

Comment: float total_price = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {

      total_price = total_price
        + (Integer.parseInt(orderItems.get(i)
                                .getNItems()) * Float
          .parseFloat(orderItems.get(i)
                                                .getItemPrice()));

Comment: @HussainAali Please *edit* your question and include all relevant details there. Also, for more and better help sooner, please put the details in your question to begin with. **How** are the results wrong? What output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: thanks sir and i'm sorry if my question is not clear ^^, i found the answer maybe my mistake is when i merge float inside string builder

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display the total cost to purchase all the items?  Such as outputting $50 if someone selects various items that together add up to $50? Elliot's answer is on the right track, but I wouldn't recommend using float or double to deal with money, due to issues with rounding and accuracy. Use BigDecimal instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i want, i found it when i read your answer, i want only the total amount ...
before when i but for example (2(item(a))*2$ +4(item(b))*1.2$) the result is com 4.04$
but now is correct thanks every body

```
total = new StringBuilder();
                float total_amount = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {

                            total_amount=total_amount+(Integer.parseInt(orderItems.get(i)
                                    .getNItems()) * Float
                                    .parseFloat(orderItems.get(i)
                                            .getItemPrice()));
                }
                total.append(total_amount);
```